# Manual excerpt customizing

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using the latest WordPress install and using HTML5 Blank WordPress Theme by [Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/HTML5-Blank-WordPress-Theme). I'm currently having issues with the EXCERPT function. I want to be able to manually type out a excerpt and have the read more link after the sentence. Not sure how to go about doing so. The the blank themes default is great, but I because of certain content... I need to be able to manually write an excerpt. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Click the "Screen Options" tab on the very top right of the screen -

There should be a checkbox for about a dozen different things - custom fields, discussion and.. **Excerpt**. Just check the box for that, and the excerpt box will pop up under the post editor allowing you to type in a manual excerpt